# Convert each item of list of tuples to string

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

How to convert

```
[('a',1),('b',3)]
```

to

```
[('a','1'),('b','3')]
```

My end goal is to get:

```
['a 1','b 3']
```

I tried:

```
[' '.join(col).strip() for col in [('a',1),('b',3)]]
```

and

```
[' '.join(str(col)).strip() for col in [('a',1),('b',3)]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
>>> x = [('a',1),('b',3)]
>>> [' '.join(str(y) for y in pair) for pair in x]
['a 1', 'b 3']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the list comprehensions in jme's answer:

```
mylist = [('a',1),('b',3)]
map(lambda xs: ' '.join(map(str, xs)), mylist)
```